# Which Oracle directory takes up the most space and why?

Tags: oracle, disk-space

Does any directory file in Oracle occupy the most space? Why does it takes up the most? e.g. system

Answer (score 2):

In a long-running, stable Oracle database instance, configured the "recommended" way, it's *probably* going to be the **Fast Recovery Area**.

That's because it holds all *sorts* of weird and wonderful things, including (but not limited to):

- Archived Redo Logs
- Database *backups*, of which there may be several
- Flashback Database logs

Not that you can do much about it.  Like most things about Oracle, it will take up as much space as it wants/needs to.  Your job in Capacity Planning your database instance(s), is basically to make sure it never runs out!

Answer (score 0):

There is no directory that *always* takes up the most space. It will depend entirely on your particular installation, the version of Oracle DB and options you are using, the number of patches installed, the size of your database, how and where you generate log files, and how your storage is configured (i.e. file system vs ASM). You should always monitor to make sure you're not using any more storage than you *expect* to use, using recommended commands like "du" above, but you will have to establish your own baseline for "normal".